# Is it possible to expand and collapse table rows/data with only css?

Tags: html, css

I have small generic table which looks something like this:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to be able to click on each table data to expand additional information. Can I do this using only css or do I have to resort to javascript?

Comment: It depends in part on where that additional information is stored in the html structure (which you do not note in your question).

Comment: hello, what do you mean by additionnal information ? is it extra content inside a cell, an extra line , an extra column ?

Comment: the additional information I would put is inside the table data, with an attribute of hidden

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can achieve this with css.
But with jQuery's `slideToggle()`, it's a piece of cake!

Comment: Isn't `toggle()` depreciated in the newer versions? You are referring to `toggleClass()`, right?

Comment: I meant `slideToggle()` acutally.. Or is that one deprecated aswell?

Comment: Nope, as far as I know, you can still use it in 1.9.1

Comment: javascript can make it cross browser, CSS can do funny things too http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/HBjDn (filter and hide/show row/column) or just toglle hide/show content http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LFkHl

Answer (score 2):

You probably will want javascript (and definitely will if you intend the item to stay open after being clicked). But to demonstrate there are instances where it can be done purely with CSS, this will work in CSS3 browsers (only while holding down the mouse button).

**[See the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/aZa58/3/)**

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>1<div>More info on 1</div></td>
    <td>2<div>More info on 2</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1<div>More info on 1</div></td>
    <td>2<div>More info on 2</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
td > div {
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

td:active > div {
    height: auto;
}
```